# Colors the code in a XLSX .template file with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, xlsx

I got a file in a VSC with the extension .template that it has all the text in white. I would like to have the text with colours depending what feature are each text.
The file with template extension has this kind of code:

```
{{xlsxRemove "xl/workbook.xml" "workbook.sheets[0].sheet" 0}}
    {{#xlsxReplace "xl/styles.xml"}}
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
            <styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr"
                xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"
                xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main"
                xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision">
```

which is a template for generate a XLSX report using https://jsreport.net/learn/xlsx.

Is it possible or need to continue working with all the text in white colour?
Regards

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: Although the title of the question looks vague. You should update it to a more descriptive one.

Anyways, this can be done with an XML extension I guess.

Comment: if you can't find an extension in the MarketPlace for XLSX you can make one yourself that has a TextMate grammar for XLSX